# Unable to create a database in cpanel using xmlapi

Tags: php, cpanel, cpanel-xmlapi

I am trying to create a new Database using my php script that includes xmlapi. I followed the steps and usage as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433355/how-does-one-go-about-creating-a-database-through-the-cpanel-whm-api). Still, I am unable to create that. On checking the error logs generated, I found the error mentioned below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
    <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=1188352635" />
    <title>Error</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/x-icon;base64,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" type="image/x-icon" />

    <!-- EXTERNAL CSS -->
    <link href="/cPanel_magic_revision_1386192030/unprotected/cpanel/fonts/open_sans/open_sans.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/cPanel_magic_revision_1542513958/unprotected/cpanel/style_v2_optimized.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <style type="text/css">
/*
  This css is included in the base template in case the css cannot be loaded because of access restrictions
  If this css is updated, please update securitypolicy_header.html.tmpl as well
*/
.copyright {
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIzNTlwdCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIzMjAiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAzNTkgMjQwIj48ZGVmcz48Y2xpcFBhdGggaWQ9ImEiPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0xMjMgMGgyMzUuMzd2MjQwSDEyM3ptMCAwIi8+PC9jbGlwUGF0aD48L2RlZnM+PHBhdGggZD0iTTg5LjY5IDU5LjEwMmg2Ny44MDJsLTEwLjUgNDAuMmMtMS42MDUgNS42LTQuNjA1IDEwLjEtOSAxMy41LTQuNDAyIDMuNC05LjUwNCA1LjA5Ni0xNS4zIDUuMDk2aC0zMS41Yy03LjIgMC0xMy41NSAyLjEwMi0xOS4wNSA2LjMtNS41MDUgNC4yLTkuMzUzIDkuOTA0LTExLjU1MiAxNy4xMDMtMS40IDUuNDAzLTEuNTUgMTAuNS0uNDUgMTUuMzAyIDEuMDk4IDQuNzk2IDMuMDQ3IDkuMDUgNS44NTIgMTIuNzUgMi43OTcgMy43MDMgNi40IDYuNjUyIDEwLjc5NyA4Ljg1IDQuMzk3IDIuMiA5LjE5OCAzLjI5OCAxNC40IDMuMjk4aDE5LjJjMy42MDIgMCA2LjU0NyAxLjQ1MyA4Ljg1MiA0LjM1MiAyLjI5NyAyLjkwMiAyLjk0NSA2LjE0OCAxLjk1IDkuNzVsLTEyIDQ0LjM5OGgtMjFjLTE0LjQwMyAwLTI3LjY1My0zLjE0OC0zOS43NS05LjQ1LTEyLjEwMi02LjMtMjIuMTUzLTE0LjY0OC0zMC4xNTMtMjUuMDUtOC0xMC4zOTUtMTMuNDU0LTIyLjI0Ni0xNi4zNS0zNS41NDctMi45LTEzLjMtMi41NS0yNi45NSAxLjA1Mi00MC45NTNsMS4yLTQuNWMyLjU5Ny05LjYwMiA2LjY0OC0xOC40NSAxMi4xNDgtMjYuNTUgNS41LTguMDk4IDEyLTE1IDE5LjUtMjAuNyA3LjUtNS43IDE1Ljg1LTEwLjE0OCAyNS4wNS0xMy4zNTIgOS4yLTMuMTk1IDE4Ljc5Ny00Ljc5NiAyOC44LTQuNzk2IiBmaWxsPSIjZmY2YzJjIi8+PGcgY2xpcC1wYXRoPSJ1cmwoI2EpIj48cGF0aCBkPSJNMTIzLjg5IDI0MEwxODIuOTkgMTguNjAyYzEuNTk4LTUuNTk4IDQuNTk4LTEwLjA5OCA5LTEzLjVDMTk2LjM4OCAxLjcgMjAxLjQ4NCAwIDIwNy4yODggMGg2Mi43YzE0LjQwMyAwIDI3LjY1IDMuMTQ4IDM5Ljc1IDkuNDUgMTIuMTAyIDYuMyAyMi4xNTMgMTQuNjU1IDMwLjE1MyAyNS4wNSA3Ljk5NyAxMC40MDIgMTMuNSAyMi4yNTQgMTYuNSAzNS41NSAzIDEzLjMwNSAyLjU5NCAyNi45NTQtMS4yMDIgNDAuOTVsLTEuMiA0LjVjLTIuNTk3IDkuNjAyLTYuNTk3IDE4LjQ1LTEyIDI2LjU1LTUuMzk4IDguMDk4LTExLjg0NyAxNS4wNTItMTkuMzQ3IDIwLjg0OC03LjUgNS44MDUtMTUuODU1IDEwLjMwNS0yNS4wNSAxMy41LTkuMiAzLjIwNC0xOC44MDUgNC44MDUtMjguODA1IDQuODA1aC01NC4yOTdsMTAuOC00MC41YzEuNi01LjQwMiA0LjYtOS44IDktMTMuMjAzIDQuMzk2LTMuMzk4IDkuNDk3LTUuMTAyIDE1LjMwMi01LjEwMmgxNy4zOThjNy4yIDAgMTMuNjUzLTIuMiAxOS4zNTItNi41OTcgNS42OTUtNC4zOTggOS40NDUtMTAuMDk3IDExLjI1LTE3LjEgMS4zOTQtNC45OTcgMS41NDctOS45LjQ0NS0xNC43LTEuMS00LjgtMy4wNS05LjA0Ny01Ljg0OC0xMi43NS0yLjgtMy42OTUtNi40MDItNi42OTUtMTAuNzk2LTktNC40MDYtMi4yOTctOS4yMDYtMy40NS0xNC40MDItMy40NUgyMzMuMzlsLTQzLjggMTYyLjkwM2MtMS42MDYgNS40LTQuNjA2IDkuNzk3LTkgMTMuMTk1LTQuNDAzIDMuNDA3LTkuNDA2IDUuMTAyLTE1IDUuMTAyaC00MS43IiBmaWxsPSIjZmY2YzJjIi8+PC9nPjwvc3ZnPgo=) no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
  background-size: 25px auto;
}
    </style>
    <!--[if IE 6]>
    <style type="text/css">
        img {
            behavior: url(/cPanel_magic_revision_1352233599/unprotected/cp_pngbehavior_login.htc);
        }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->

    <script>
    window.DOM = { get: function(id) { return document.getElementById(id) } };
    </script>
</head>
<body class="">




    <p class="logo"><img class="main-logo" src="/cPanel_magic_revision_1457841996/unprotected/cpanel/images/cpanel-logo.svg" alt="logo"></p>



<div class="error_notice">
    <div id="error-wrapper">
        <div id="error_msg_contents">
            <h2>HTTP error 404</h2>
    <p>The requested page was not found.</p>
    <h2>Possible reasons why you are seeing this page:</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>A bookmarked URL may have changed since you last visited.</li>
        <li>The URL was entered incorrectly.</li>
        <li>The URL was entered with inaccurate capitalization (URLs are <a href="http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity">case sensitive</a>).</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Please re-check the URL you are trying to reach. (<a href="javascript:history.back()">Go Back</a>)</p>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="copyright">Copyright© 2019 cPanel, Inc.
    <br /><a href="https://go.cpanel.net/privacy" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a></div>

</body>

</html>
```

My php code snippet is as follows:

```html
<?php
    require("../libs/xmlapi.php"); // this can be downlaoded from https://github.com/CpanelInc/xmlapi-php/blob/master/xmlapi.php

    class CpanelOperation {
        private $cpanelCred = array("url"=>"localhost","port"=>2083,"user"=>"myCpanelUsername", "pwd"=>"MyCpanelpwd");
        private $xmlapi;
        private $dbUser = array("userName"=>"dbUserName","pwd"=>"dbuserPwd"); // The user already exists and has access to other DB's

        public function __construct(){
            $this->xmlapi = new xmlapi($this->cpanelCred['url']);
            $this->xmlapi->set_port($this->cpanelCred['port']);  
            $this->xmlapi->password_auth("".$this->cpanelCred['user']."","".$this->cpanelCred['pwd']."");    
            $this->xmlapi->set_debug(1);//output actions in the error log 1 for true and 0 false 
        }
        public function createDB($dbName){
            //create database    
            $createdb = $this->xmlapi->api1_query($this->cpanelCred['user'], "Mysql", "adddb", array($dbName));
            if($createdb){
                $user = $this->assignUser($dbName);
                if($user){
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    echo "User not assgned to the DB";
                }
            }
            else{
                echo "Unable to create db in cpanel again!";
            }
        }

        public function assignUser($dbName){
            $dbNameInCPanel = $this->cpanelCred['user']."_".$dbName;
            $userInCPanel = $this->cpanelCred['user']."_".$this->dbUser['userName'];
            //add user 
            $addusr = $this->xmlapi->api1_query($this->cpanelCred['user'], "Mysql", "adduserdb", array($dbNameInCPanel, $userInCPanel, 'all'));
        }
    }
?>
```

Any clue on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance! Am new to PHP, so please bear with me if I sound silly!

Answer (score 0):

Okay.. So after a hell lot of research and trial and hits, i finally managed to figure this out. I am putting the solution right here so that it might help someone facing similar issues.

Instead of using xmlapi, I have used the uapi and the following code snippet will create a DB and grant user access to the same.

```html
<?php
    require("../libs/cpaneluapi.class.php");

    class CpanelUAPIOperation {
        private $cpanelCred = array("url"=>"localhost","port"=>2087,"user"=>"cpanelUser", "pwd"=>"cpanelPwd");
        private $dbUser = array("userName"=>"dbUser","pwd"=>"dbpwd");
        private $cpanel;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->cpanel = new cpanelAPI($this->cpanelCred['user'], $this->cpanelCred['pwd'], $this->cpanelCred['url']); //instantiate the object
        }
        
        public function createDB($dbName, $crud){
            $dbNameInCPanel = $this->cpanelCred['user']."_".$dbName;
            $createDB = $this->cpanel->uapi->Mysql->create_database(array('name' => $dbNameInCPanel)); //Create the database
            if($createDB){
                 $databaseuser = $this->cpanelCred['user']."_".$this->dbUser['userName'];
                 // Assign the user to have access to the database.
                 $access = $this->cpanel->uapi->set_privileges_on_database(array('user' => $databaseuser, 'database' => $dbNameInCPanel, 'privileges' => 'ALL'));
                 if($access){
                     $crud->switchDB($dbNameInCPanel);
                     return true;
                 }
            }   
            return false;
        }
    }
?>
```

That's pretty much it! :)